# Using WorldAnchorManager from MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, hololens

at the moment I try to use the experimental WorldAnchorManager (see [official API entry](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Experimental.Utilities.WorldAnchorManager.html)) of MRTK 2.4. Over all everything looks quiet easy. First of all, you have to create an Instance of the Manager and assign it to the script where you want to use it. Afterwards, it should be possible to load an anchor into a object with this piece of code:

```
public string AttachAnchor(GameObject gameObjectToAnchor, string anchorName = null)
```

This code also saves the Anchor as mentioned in the API.

If I want to remove the anchor from a GameObject I can call:

```
public void RemoveAnchor(GameObject gameObjectToUnanchor)
```

In my Unity-Project (2019.3.7) I calculate a position of some gameobjects and afterwards assign them Anchors via the Method above. If I move the Gameobjects, I remove the anchors and attatch them again after the moving process is finished.

If I deploy the solution on HoloLens2, position the gameobjects, attatch the anchors and get a log that the anchors have been attatched successfully, those anchors should be accessable on hololens2 locally across sessions. Unfortunately, in my case after restarting the application on the device and reloading the anchors, they cant be loaded. The Manager Logs "Anchor could not be loaded for '*GO name*' ... creating a new anchor".

I am not sure what I did wrong, should this Manager already work? Do I have to Configure something in the Unity-Project to use the Manager? Maybe someone already uses the Manager and can help me with this issue.

Comment: Since WorldAnchorManager is an Experimental feature, it is early in the cycle and haven’t graduate it into core MRTK code. 
It has not documentation show how to use it for now. However, according to the source code of WorldAnchorManager, you get this issue because WorldAnchorStore.Load returned null in [line 440](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/62d2b2b2113792e4a735167068e7548258a93fd0/Assets/MRTK/SDK/Experimental/Features/Utilities/WorldAnchorManager.cs#L440). So you should double-check that the WorldAnchorStore.Save method in line 568 returns true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already in the debugging process. Can you maybe rule out that the OS version of my HoloLens is a possible reason for the problem?

Comment: It should not be, it uses Unity API and has nothing to do with the OS version.

Comment: Besides, for Unity version, we recommend the Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version to use, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.10f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is far too late, I want to finish this question. The WorldAnchorManager only functions when built for the WSA platform using legacy XR. It doesn´t work within the editor or with the Unity-XR-Plugin. I tried to use it with the XR-Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I wrote a small example app that uses the world anchor manager from MRTK.
Based on these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/persistence-in-unity, the app enables the user to place a cube at any location, automatically creating and saving an anchor each time the cube is released.
When the app is closed and re-started, the anchor is loaded and the cube is placed at its saved location.

The source can be found here: https://github.com/anders-lundgren/mrtk-world-anchors

Verified on Unity 2019.4.9f1, Visual Studio 2019, HoloLens 2 (Build 10.0.19041.1377).

In addition to the above steps, I added the base MRTK components, according to the MRTK getting started tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02. I also added a simple debugging prefab from this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-asa-02#importing-the-tutorial-assets, and the manipulation handler from this example: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ManipulationHandler.html.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I imported your MakeAngle-Script. Unfortunately, saving anchors still always results in "false". I already tried the approach you referenced to with the first link before I wrote this Question but it didn´t work at that time and it still doesn´t work now. I am working with Unity 2019.4.7 and with the xr-plugin. Currently I am really out of ideas what could be the reason behind that.